# Can using multiple analytic packages become a problem?

Tags: performance, google-analytics, analytics

We are launching a new company next month, and I am curious about what analytic package to use.  My current thought is maybe just use two or three together.  Would there be any serious performance issues by doing so?

Specifically we're thinking of: [Reinvigorate](http://reinvigorate.net/) and [Kiss Metrics](https://www.kissmetrics.com)

And maybe Google Analytics too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing multiple web analytic packages is not necessarily a bad thing.  I see clients do it all the time.  The main benefit is that in case one tool goes down or has some kind of issue, you have a backup. Another benefit is that one tool may offer a lot of insight for you but maybe it lacks in certain features that another tool has.  Or you have different stakeholders asking different questions and sometimes its easier to just use a separate tool for separate people to avoid conflict in data between the two.

HOWEVER

Please Please PLEASE do not fall into the way too common trap of trying to compare numbers between tools! Or at least, try to suppress your gut reaction to ask why there is a difference.  There is a 95% chance you will needlessly waste much time and resources on everybody's part trying to track down a phantom bug that more than likely does not exist, or is otherwise unexplainable and falls under the acceptable margin of error category.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen commercial (major brand company-type) sites use somewhere around 15-20+ simultaneously according to ghostery. Doesn't really seem like it, async them all

Comment: 99% of the time you see this, it is a due to a lack of coordination and communication internally.  Big companies have all these departments and random stakeholders and rather than go through the effort to find out if there is already tracking somewhere, already reports available, they just start from scratch with a new implementation. Half the time it's a "better safe than sorry" move, not wanting to somehow mess up the implementation.  You'd be surprised at how little companies keep track of things like this.